# 球の重なりを色分けで判断できるようにしたい

Tags: matplotlib

複数の球を作り球同士の重なりがある場合は、重なり部分をわかりやすく色分けするように描写できるようにしたいのですがどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。
複数の球を作るところまではできたのですが、それ以降をどのようにすればいいのかわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

重なり合う部分は２個以上の球の内部にあります。

それを見えるように表示するために、次のようにすれば良いと思われます。
１）球面は半透明で表示する（球の内部にある重なり合う部分が見えるように）
２）重なり合う部分の球面は、不透明な色で表示する（重なり部分であることが判るように）

重なりのある１つの球の表面を同じ色の半透明と不透明で表示し、色を各球で異なるようにすれば（色で球が判別できるようにすれば）更に良いのではないでしょうか。